# Cannot start Rack server because of NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm writing a tiny Sinatra application (Facebook Messenger bot), so I'm using `facebook-messenger` gem. Here's what I've got in my `config.ru`:

```
require './app'
require_relative 'bot'

require 'facebook/messenger'
include Facebook::Messenger


map '/webhook' do
  run Sinatra::Application
  run Facebook::Messenger::Server
end
```

But anytime I try to launch my server with `rackup -p 5000` command, it returns me the following error:

```
/chatbot/config.ru:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `include' for #<Rack::Builder:0x007feb32926e70> (NoMethodError)
```

What can be the reason of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content of config.ru file is handled by Rack::Builder, not by Ruby itself. Specificaly the include line is evaluated in context of Rack::Builder and that gives you the undefined method. According to the rest of the code, you dont need to include it as you use full path to the inner Module/Class

```
run Facebook::Messenger::Server
```

If you realy need to include it, do so in separete (ruby) file and require that file in config.ru.